# Receiving headset clicks

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to find out how it would be possible to receive button clicks made with a headset connected to a Windows Phone 7 device and respond to this accordingly.
I'm quite new to WP7 development, but as a reference, the Android equivalent would be through registering a BroadcastReceiver. Does WP7 have a similar concept, possibly with a way to manage when to let my app receive it or when to let to go through to another app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API in the WP7 SDK for determining when someone clicks a button on the headset.

For a complete reference on whats possible check out the following links:

1. [Windows Phone Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402535%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)
2. [Class Library Reference for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626516.aspx)

Comment: That's what I was fearing. Thanks for the confirmation anyway.